# Figuring out bottleneck in Cloud ML training

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-ml-engine

I'm trying to train [DCGAN](https://github.com/carpedm20/DCGAN-tensorflow) on celebA. The training process seems to be going very slowly, and I want to figure out what is causing the bottleneck. The time it would take to train for one epoch seems to be very similar when I use scale tier STANDARD_1, BASIC_GPU, or just run locally on my 6 year old 4-core CPU laptop. On these three configurations, each training step takes about 25 seconds, although I noticed that every once in a while a training step will take a few minutes.

When using BASIC_GPU, the cpu utilization is less than .1. I ran an experiment using the BASIC tier, and master hovers at .4 and takes about 40 seconds per step. When using STANDARD_1, I get the following cpu utilization:

- master: .28
- worker: .21
- parameter server (ps): .48

When running on BASIC which uses a single worker, shouldn't the CPU utilization be close to 100%?

At this rate, it's going to take 22 hours to train one epoch of celebA with the images downscaled to 64x64. Looking at other people's training logs from the repo, it looks like this is significantly higher than other people training with a GPU.

Comment: Can you provide a pointer to the other training logs you mention?

Comment: This person seems to be averaging less than 2 seconds per batch: https://github.com/carpedm20/DCGAN-tensorflow/issues/34

Answer (score 1):

I am just guessing here -- but from taking a look at the code you point, the training does two things:

1. Uses feeding, i.e. loading data in python -- using reader queues (https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/reading_data) might be faster.
2. This is more likely. The code reads a file at a time, or a batch of files, but each results in a separate request to cloud storage, so doesn't benefit from optimizations like buffering etc. This means your code might be I/O bound, and that might explain the lower CPU usage. Additionally, adding GPU might further offload work onto the GPU, and reduce CPU utilization ... which is still busy doing I/O.

Not sure if this helps, but it might provide some pointers.